# Access Instr Vba

Tags: string, vba, comparison, field

i want to copy bi!hersteller and bi!produktname into a new field
but when bi!hersteller is already in bi!produktname it shall only copy bi!produktname into the new field, so i'll show you, which codes i already tried

```
 If InStr(1, Bi!Hersteller, Bi!Produktname, 1) > 0 Then ....

 If InStr(1, Bi!Hersteller, Bi!Produktname, 1) Len(Bi!Hersteller) Then ....
```

Either it doesnt find the string Bi!Hersteller in Bi!Produktname at all, or the return of InStr is Incorrect...

An Example

```
Bi!Hersteller = "Siemens"
Bi!Produktname = "Siemens LC67KA532"
```

New Field should be `"Siemens LC67KA532"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim sNewField
Dim Bi!Hersteller : Bi!Hersteller = "Siemens"
Dim Bi!Produktname : Bi!Produktname = "Siemens LC67KA532"

If InStr(Bi!Produktname, Bi!Hersteller) > 0 Then
   sNewField = Bi!Produktname
Else
   sNewField = Bi!Hersteller & Bi!Produktname
End If
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the fast answer, just solved it right now by just exchanging the two...

InStr(1, Bi!Produktname, Bi!Hersteller, 1) > 0, this worked fine, but thanks for your efford :)

Comment: You are welcome! Consider to mark the question as answered